# Facebook graph API is not returning share count of a post

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get total share count of a post by using Facebook graph API. According to the graph API doc provided by Facebook (1), if I request a post with field `shares`, it would return the share count of that post.

For example,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{post-id}?shares&access_token=xxxx
```

I also tried to put the summary parameter(summary=1) in the url to get the shared count, but it is not returning any shared count. On the other hand, `likes` and `comments` total counts are returned using the same method. Am I missing something here?

1. [Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post)

Comment: Are there any shares? Are you able to see those shares? (and do you definitely have a page access token for the page which made the post?)

Comment: Yes. There are definitely shares, I have check them manually. My post-id type is rather an object id that I get from a web URL that has Facebook likes and share button.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect.  To access a field, your parameter should be fields=XXX, like this:

`https://graph.facebook.com/{post-id}?fields=shares&access_token=xxxx`